# Predict mclust cluster membership outside R

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis, prediction

I've used mclust to find clusters in a dataset. Now I want to implement these findings into external non-r software (predict.Mclust is thus not an option as has been suggested in previous similar Questions) to classify new observations. I need to know *how* mclust classifies observations.

Since mclust outputs a center and a covariance matrix for each cluster it felt reasonable to calculate mahalanobis distance for every observation and for every cluster. Observations could then be classified to the mahalonobi-nearest cluster. It seems not not to work fully however.

Example code with simulated data (in this example I only use one dataset, d, and try to obtain the same classification as mclust does by the mahalanobi approach outlined above):

```
set.seed(123)
c1<-mvrnorm(100,mu=c(0,0),Sigma=matrix(c(2,0,0,2),ncol=2))
c2<-mvrnorm(200,mu=c(3,3),Sigma=matrix(c(3,0,0,3),ncol=2))

d<-rbind(c1,c2)
m<-Mclust(d)

int_class<-m$classification

clust1_cov<-m$parameters$variance$sigma[,,1]
clust1_center<-m$parameters$mean[,1]
clust2_cov<-m$parameters$variance$sigma[,,2]
clust2_center<-m$parameters$mean[,2]

mahal_clust1<-mahalanobis(d,cov=clust1_cov,center=clust1_center)
mahal_clust2<-mahalanobis(d,cov=clust2_cov,center=clust2_center)
mahal_clust_dist<-cbind(mahal_clust1,mahal_clust2)

mahal_classification<-apply(mahal_clust_dist,1,function(x){ 
  match(min(x),x)
})

table(int_class,mahal_classification)
#List mahalanobis distance for miss-classified observations:
mahal_clust_dist[mahal_classification!=int_class,]

plot(m,what="classification")
#Indicate miss-classified observations:
points(d[mahal_classification!=int_class,],pch="X")

#Results:
> table(int_class,mahal_classification)
         mahal_classification
int_class   1   2
        1 124   0
        2   5 171
> mahal_clust_dist[mahal_classification!=int_class,]
     mahal_clust1 mahal_clust2
[1,]     1.340450     1.978224
[2,]     1.607045     1.717490
[3,]     3.545037     3.938316
[4,]     4.647557     5.081306
[5,]     1.570491     2.193004
```

Five observations are classified differently between the mahalanobi approach and mclust. In the plots they are intermediate points between the two clusters. Could someone tell me why it does not work and how I could mimic the internal classification of mclust and predict.Mclust?

Comment: this may help: http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr597.pdf

Answer (score 0):

After formulating the above question I did some additional research (thx LoBu) and found that the key was to calculate the posterior probability (pp) for an observation to belong to a certain cluster and classify according to maximal pp. The following works:

```
denom<-rep(0,nrow(d))
pp_matrix<-matrix(rep(NA,nrow(d)*2),nrow=nrow(d))
for(i in 1:2){
  denom<-denom+m$parameters$pro[i]*dmvnorm(d,m$parameters$mean[,i],m$parameters$variance$sigma[,,i])
}
for(i in 1:2){
  pp_matrix[,i]<-m$parameters$pro[i]*dmvnorm(d,m$parameters$mean[,i],m$parameters$variance$sigma[,,i]) / denom
}

pp_class<-apply(pp_matrix,1,function(x){ 
  match(max(x),x)
})
table(pp_class,m$classification)
#Result:
pp_class   1   2
       1 124   0
       2   0 176
```

But if someone in layman terms could explain the difference between the mahalanobi and pp approach I would be greatful. What do the "mixing probabilities" (m$parameters$pro) signify?

Comment: This solution appears not to be general. When running the code in mclust 5.4.7 I get one missclassified observation. Testing different models (EII, VII and EEI) yields different small numbers of missclassified observations and plotting m$uncertainty against apply(pp_matrix,1,function(x){ 1-max(x)}) shows that mclust uncertainty and calculated uncertainty differs somewhat. Why is that so? Is it enough to account for sigma and mean, as in above example, or do Sigma, Cholsigma, Scale, Orientation etc play a part in the different types of model specifications?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mahalanobis distance, you *also* need to take the cluster *weight* into account.

These weight the relative importance of clusters when they overlap.